# How play swf files from assets android (API 21+)?

Tags: android, android-studio, flash, webview

I'm trying to run a swf file in a WebView
But I have nothing displayed
Although the same file I can run through the application Dolphin Video means it is possible
How to do it?

My code

```
    webView?.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true;
    webView?.settings?.allowFileAccess = true;
    webView?.settings?.useWideViewPort = false
    webView?.settings?.loadWithOverviewMode = false
    webView?.settings?.setSupportZoom(false)
    webView?.settings?.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
    webView?.settings?.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
    webView?.settings?.databaseEnabled = true
    webView?.settings?.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView?.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

    var html = "<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> " +
            "<param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/test.swf\"> " +
            "<embed src=\"file:///android_asset/test.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> " +
            "</embed> </object>"
    var mimeType = "text/html"
    var encoding = "utf-8"

    webView?.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "")
```

Just showing white screen

Comment: I don't think android webview support flash. Just try to load a webpage with flash content (swf games) on webview and check how that goes. I could be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work